# Monogame Dragging 3D object edges

Tags: xna, 3d, monogame, blender

I am having trouble rendering 3D models with monogame.
The problem only occurs when I export the object from blender with two materials on it. Example: [image]

Monogame sees those two different materials and renders them correctly.
Here comes the problem.. When you start moving the object around you can clearly see the edges which are with the snow material dragging or glitching. Image to see what I mean: [image] 
As you can see the edges on the bottom with the Stone_Normal material appear ok but the edges with the snow material are glitching. This is only happening when you move the object around and it doesn't have to be fast. In this example, I am just rotating the object around its axis.

Answer (score 1):

Can't really tell from the image but it could be z flickering. Are you using an unnecessary high far clip value?

Also, how does your transformations handle rotations? I guess your model is divided in sub meshes. Are the rotation and local matrix each mesh working as expected? Can you post the render code?